# Why, after the salutation and name of addressee, followed by a comma, is the following word capitalized?

Tags: letter-writing

In a letter of any sort, why do most people capitalize the first word after the comma that follows the name of the addressee? I was taught (at Cambridge, England) not to do so! For example:

> Dear Mr. Black, in relation to our stated plan to.... etc.

was the way I was taught.

> Dear Mr. Black, In relation to our stated plan to... etc.

is incorrect, is it not?

Comment: This would be better on [Writing.SE]

Answer (score 4):

If it's in a formal letter, the format is usually as follows:

> Dear Mr. Smith,
>
> In relation to our stated plan…

The *dear* is merely a salutation, not a sentence. *In relation* starts an actual sentence because it's in the body of the letter, so it needs to be capitalized.

Comment: That is certainly the writing convention, though I agree with the OP that it is illogical.

Comment: @WS2 for me it depends on whether there's a paragraph break. No break: lower case. Paragraph break: upper case.

Comment: @curiousdannii yes, which only makes it more illogical. Just try ending a paragraph with a comma in any other context.

Comment: @RegDwigнt If you were looking for logic then language isn't the field for you :P

Comment: @Reg Sure. Before a blockquote that's part of a sentence, you split up the paragraph and can end with a comma just fine. The capitalisation is a result of starting a _visual_ paragraph (a block element of text); the notional paragraph (the sentences that make up a semantically distinct group) is not ended with the comma at all—it just spans several visual paragraphs, just like when you have a blockquote inside a sentence/paragraph.